# Improve socket speed

Tags: python, performance, sockets, networking

I'm working on a multiplayer game with sockets and decided to test out connecting to the server from a different machine. I was able to connect to the sever but the only thing is that there was a bit of lag. There would be spikes where the other player would stop and them teleport back to where they should be. These weren't very large spikes, it would only last for about 4/6th of a second, but it was noticeable. I know when I expand on the game, the sever is going to slow down even more to the point where it is almost unplayable, so I asked here to hopefully find out about good ways to speed up the server. I did a little bit of speed testing, and this is what I got:

```
# Buffer recv - 0.015977859497070312
# update_client - typically around 0.00017213821411132812, but sometimes spikes to 9.202957153320312e-05
# sending data - around 0.0001914501190185547, but every other time, it spikes to 8.416175842285156e-05
```

It's not very much, but it might be helpful. Here's the code for every test above.

Recv Buffer Code:

```
data = ""
recv_data = conn.recv(bufsize)
if recv_data == b'':
    print(f"{player_id} DISCONNECTED")
    break
message_length = int(recv_data[:HEADER_SIZE])
data += recv_data.decode()
while True:
    if len(data)-HEADER_SIZE >= message_length:
        if len(data)-HEADER_SIZE > message_length:
            conn.setblocking(0)
            while True:
                try:
                    extra_data = conn.recv(bufsize)
                    if not extra_data:
                        break
                except:
                    break
            conn.setblocking(1)
        break
    recv_data = conn.recv(bufsize)
    data += recv_data.decode()
data = data[HEADER_SIZE:message_length+HEADER_SIZE]
```

Update_client Code (I use a new thread for each client)

```
def update_client(updatemessage,target_socket):
    """
    update_data[0][0] is the player's x pos
    update_data[0][1] is the player's y pos
    update_data[1] is the player's flip bool
    update_data[2] is the player's name str

    :param updatemessage:
    :param target_socket:
    :return:
    """
    
    # player key structure in playermap: {playerid:[[x,y],flip,name,been_hit]}
    update_data = json.loads(updatemessage) # Data received from the passed client
    updates = [key for key in update_data.keys()] # All keys in the dict sent from client
    player_update_lst = update_data[updates[0]] # Player locations update data
    mini_update_lst = update_data[updates[1]] # Mini game update data
    playerid = player_update_lst[0] # The id of the player client sending this data

    if playerid == 0: # Prevent sending data to the server itself
        return
        
    update = {'player locations':[],"mini-update":[]} # Empty update dict
    if start_game and playerid not in updated_clients:
        update["map-update"] = start_game[1]
        updated_clients.append(playerid)
        if sorted([key for key in playermap.keys()]) == sorted(updated_clients):
            print("Clearing")
            start_game.clear()
            updated_clients.clear()
    
    if playerid != 1:
        if playerid not in playermap.keys():
            playerid -= 1
        elif playerid - 1 not in playermap.keys():
            pdata = playermap[playerid]
            playermap.pop(playerid)
            playerid -= 1
            playermap[playerid] = pdata
            update = {"id update":playerid,'player locations':[],"mini-update":[]}
    else:
        if mini_update_lst[2]:
            minigame, minimap = get_minimap()
            update["map-update"] = minimap
            start_game.append(minigame)
            start_game.append(minimap)
            print("starting game")
                        
    # Player locations update stuff
    playermap[playerid][0][0] = player_update_lst[1] # player.x
    playermap[playerid][0][1] = player_update_lst[2] # player.y
    playermap[playerid][1] = player_update_lst[3] # player.flip
    playermap[playerid][2] = player_update_lst[4] # player.name
    playermap[playerid][4] = player_update_lst[5]  # player.been_hit

    # Mini game update stuff
    hit_player = mini_update_lst[0] # hit_player (the id of the player that the client hit)
    if hit_player:
        playermap[hit_player][3] = playermap[playerid][0] # Goes to the id of the hit player in playermap and changes the "False"
                                                          # value at index 3, to the position of the player that hit the other player.
    playermap[playerid][5] = mini_update_lst[1] # player.score (KOTH: The time in seconds the player has been on the platform)

    # Looping over every connected player to send to the selected client. Used for changes to the player's position or look.
    # (by "look", I mean the flip value which flips the player's image, and the hit value which changes the player img's hue)
    score_update_lst = []
    for key, value in playermap.items():
        # key is the player's id
        # value[0][0] is the player's x position
        # value[0][1] is the player's y position
        # value[1] is the player's flip value
        # value[2] is the player's name
        # value[3] is the player's attacker pos value (stores the position of the attacker if hit)
        # value[4] is the player's been_hit value (used for the player flash when hit)
        # value[5] is the player's score value (used for minigames)
        update['player locations'].append([key, value[0][0], value[0][1], value[1], value[2], value[4]])
        score_update_lst.append([value[2],value[5]])
    update["mini-update"].append(score_update_lst)

    # Knockback stuff. If the player has been hit, the position of the attacker will be stored at playermap[playerid][3].
    # If there is data there, the code in the if statement is excuted
    if playermap[playerid][3]:
        update['mini-update'].append(playermap[playerid][3])
        playermap[playerid][3] = False
    else:
        update['mini-update'].append(False)

    # Sending the data to the client, but if there is a error, the client socket is removed
    try:
        #print(json.dumps(update).encode())
        send_data = json.dumps(update)
        target_socket.sendall((f"{len(send_data):<{HEADER_SIZE}}"+send_data).encode())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        
    return playerid
```

Sending data code:

```
try:
    #print(json.dumps(update).encode())
    send_data = json.dumps(update)
    target_socket.sendall((f"{len(send_data):<{HEADER_SIZE}}"+send_data).encode())
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}"
```

Does anyone know how to make any of those code snippets faster? If you need extra information or code, feel free to ask :).

Comment: Doing a non-blocking-`recv()` in a loop until you have received the number of bytes you wanted is the same as doing a blocking-`recv()` except less CPU-efficient, since it spins the CPU while it waits.  In either case, your receiving thread will not be able to do anything else until the desired data has been collected, which could be milliseconds, seconds, minutes, or never.  A better approach is to always do a non-blocking I/O, and if you get a short read, store the received bytes in a local buffer somewhere and then continue your regular event loop until you get the rest.

Comment: That's helpful, although, that's not the problem. That bit of code is basically never executed. The only reason it's there is to clear the recv buffer just in case any extra data is sent.

Comment: For fun, write a client that sends the first part of a command, and then calls `sleep(100)`, before sending the rest of the bytes, and see how your server handles it.  (and if you're thinking that a real client can be trusted never to do that, consider that any client whose network connectivity gets interrupted after sending the first bytes of a command but before it can send the rest of the bytes of the command will, from the server's point of view, appear to be behaving that same way).  A dropped packet would cause a similar server-side delay, albeit a shorter one.